# Как вывести введенные данные с админки на HTML страницу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Всем привет! Как отобразить данные на странице? 
Мои жалкие попытки не принесли результатов.
views.py

```
def Retro(request):
    retro = RetrospectiveField.get(id=1)
    return render(request, "conclusions1/example.html", {"retro": retro})
```

models.py

```
class ConclusionName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RetrospectiveField(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     conclusionName = models.ForeignKey(ConclusionName)
     baseText = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     comments = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

conclusion.html

```
<body>          
        <h3>Приложение 2 "Ретроспектива"</h3>
    {% for effect in RetrospectiveField %}
        <p>{{ retro.baseText }}</p>
        <p>{{ retro.comments }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
```

**UPD:**

Для сохранения данных на основной странице использовано это. Я переделала под свое. Не знаю что надо прописать в form_retrospective_field.html, view_retrof.html.

```
def add_form_retrospective_field(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RetrospectiveFieldForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            retro = RetrospectiveField()
            retro.user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            retro.project = form.cleaned_data.get('project')
            retro.conclusionName = form.cleaned_data.get('conclusionName')
            retro.baseText = form.cleaned_data.get('baseText')
            retro.comments = form.cleaned_data.get('comments')
            retro.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RetrospectiveFieldForm()
    return render(request, 'conclusion1/form_retrospective_field.html', {'form': form})



def showRetrospectiveField(request, slug):
    projects = Project.objects.filter(id=slug)
    retrof = RetrospectiveField.objects.get(project=projects)
    return render(request, 'conclusion1/view_retrof.html', {'retrof': retrof})
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Вы используете неправильную инструкцию для получения экземпляра с конкретным `id`.

Замените её на:

```py
RetrospectiveField.objects.get(id=1)
```

2) Вы рендерите не тот шаблон, что привели в вопросе. Структуру проекта я не знаю, но обратите на это внимание.

Должно быть примерно так, если шаблон - `conclusion.html`:

```py
render(request, 'conclusion.html')
```

3) Вы пытаетесь итерировать экземпляр *(?)* . `id` - это `pk` *(primary key)* поле. Оно уникально. Поэтому не может быть несколько экземпляров с одинаковым `id`.

Уберите цикл:

```html
<body>          
    <p>{{ retro.baseText }}</p>
    <p>{{ retro.comments }}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: А как сохранить выведенный текст на странице, т.е. даже после обновления страницы или закрытия вкладки? И еще. если не по id, у меня несколько проектов (models.py поле project), т.е для каждого проекта своя страница conclusion.html?

Comment: @Jhmxtp _"А как сохранить выведенный текст на странице, т.е. даже после обновления страницы или закрытия вкладки?"_ - Увы, я плохо понимаю, о чём Вы.

Comment: @Jhmxtp *"И еще. если не по id, у меня несколько проектов (models.py поле project), т.е для каждого проекта своя страница conclusion.html?"* - необязательно. Вы можете делать универсальные шаблоны. Также можно использовать наследование и расширение. Почитайте про теги `{% extends %}` и `{% include %}`.

Comment: Когда в админке я заполняю поля класса и сохраняю, то они должны отобразиться в HTML странице. Как сохранить, чтобы даже после перезагрузки страницы или закрытия вкладки, информация на страница оставалась

Comment: @Jhmxtp То есть, Вы хотите, чтобы при изменении данных, они не менялись у тех, кто их уже увидел? Думаю, что это довольно сложно сделать.

Comment: Добавила в вопросе код, посмотрите выше